# How to convert hexadecimal to decimal in a substitution statement?

Tags: vim

I have a line like this:

> pad (2) = 0x0041

I wanna change the hex into decimal and the expected result is

> pad (2) = 65

I just tried `:%s/\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\1 = \=printf("%d", submatch(2))`, but it failed.

Would you help to solve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vim has a `str2nr()` function to convert different number representations to their decimal values. To convert hex values you could use it like this:

```
s/0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+/\=str2nr(submatch(0), 16)
```

Comment: oh. Thank you very much and your method is quite useful.
but if there are [a-f] in the statement the method fails.

Comment: @stefan: Oops, yes of course :), I should extend the match to also include those characters...

Comment: slightly more readable imho:

`s/0x[[:xdigit:]]\+/\=str2nr(submatch(0), 16)`

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost ok, but, according to the documentation:

> When the substitute string **starts** with "\=" the remainder is interpreted as an
>   expression.  This does not work recursively: a substitute() function inside
>   the expression cannot use "\=" for the substitute string.

So, you may change your code to

```
%s/\(.*\) = \(.*\)/\=submatch(1)." = ".printf("%d", submatch(2))
```

Comment: Hi ZyX, 
Thank you very much. I will try your method. Now I have a good way to convert my logs. :-)

Comment: if you're not changing anything in the first half (just matching), you might want to consider using `\zs` to change where the start of the replaced string is:

Comment: `%s/pad(.*) = \zs0x[0-9a-fA-F]\+/\=print("%d", submatch(2))`